# converting dates in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix that is 9660 x 51. The first column is dates. I used `datenum` to convert the dates and then `datestr` to display the dates. But I want to create a for loop that will display the dates and the data from the entire matrix.

For example:

```
'12/31/11'  '18:00' '9722'  'Millbrook' '13.05' '1.763' '1.14'  '0.791' '1.589' 
'12/31/11'  '17:00' '9721'  'Millbrook' '13.03' '1.763' '1.138' '0.789' '1.58'  
'12/31/11'  '16:00' '9720'  'Millbrook' '12.98' '1.763' '1.138' '0.786' '1.565' 
'12/31/11'  '15:00' '9719'  'Millbrook' '13.14' '1.76'  '1.138' '0.786' '1.555' 
'12/31/11'  '14:00' '9718'  'Millbrook' '13.13' '1.76'  '1.138' '0.786' '1.558' 
'12/31/11'  '13:00' '9717'  'Millbrook' '13.19' '1.76'  '1.135' '0.784' '1.567' 
'12/31/11'  '12:00' '9716'  'Millbrook' '13.16' '1.76'  '1.133' '0.781' '1.594' 
'12/31/11'  '11:00' '9715'  'Millbrook' '13.15' '1.758' '1.133' '0.781' '1.626' 
'12/31/11'  '10:00' '9714'  'Millbrook' '13.1'  '1.758' '1.13'  '0.781' '1.663' 
'12/31/11'  '9:00'  '9713'  'Millbrook' '12.81' '1.758' '1.13'  '0.781' '1.689' 
'12/31/11'  '8:00'  '9712'  'Millbrook' '12.81' '1.758' '1.13'  '0.781' '1.697' 
'12/31/11'  '7:00'  '9711'  'Millbrook' '13.02' '1.758' '1.133' '0.786' '1.699' 
'12/31/11'  '6:00'  '9710'  'Millbrook' '13.02' '1.76'  '1.138' '0.793' '1.707' 
'12/31/11'  '5:00'  '9709'  'Millbrook' '13.02' '1.763' '1.143' '0.801' '1.719' 
'12/31/11'  '4:00'  '9708'  'Millbrook' '13.03' '1.765' '1.145' '0.801' '1.729' 
'12/31/11'  '3:00'  '9707'  'Millbrook' '13.03' '1.763' '1.143' '0.801' '1.741' 
'12/31/11'  '2:00'  '9706'  'Millbrook' '13.03' '1.763' '1.143' '0.801' '1.748' 
'12/31/11'  '1:00'  '9705'  'Millbrook' '13.04' '1.763' '1.143' '0.801' '1.753' 
'12/31/11'  '0:00'  '9704'  'Millbrook' '13.04' '1.763' '1.14'  '0.798' '1.763'
```

To simplify it I want to be able to look at the whole entire matrix but by day.

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't really have to convert the dates to group them by day. Just get the unique dates and iterate over them like this:

```
myData = {
'12/31/11' '18:00' '9722' 'Millbrook' '13.05' '1.763' '1.14' '0.791' '1.589' 
'12/31/11' '17:00' '9721' 'Millbrook' '13.03' '1.763' '1.138' '0.789' '1.58'
'12/31/11' '16:00' '9720' 'Millbrook' '12.98' '1.763' '1.138' '0.786' '1.565' 
'12/31/11' '15:00' '9719' 'Millbrook' '13.14' '1.76' '1.138' '0.786' '1.555' 
'12/31/11' '14:00' '9718' 'Millbrook' '13.13' '1.76' '1.138' '0.786' '1.558' 
'12/31/11' '13:00' '9717' 'Millbrook' '13.19' '1.76' '1.135' '0.784' '1.567'
'12/31/11' '12:00' '9716' 'Millbrook' '13.16' '1.76' '1.133' '0.781' '1.594' 
'12/31/11' '11:00' '9715' 'Millbrook' '13.15' '1.758' '1.133' '0.781' '1.626' 
'12/31/11' '10:00' '9714' 'Millbrook' '13.1' '1.758' '1.13' '0.781' '1.663' 
'12/31/11' '9:00' '9713' 'Millbrook' '12.81' '1.758' '1.13' '0.781' '1.689'
'12/31/11' '8:00' '9712' 'Millbrook' '12.81' '1.758' '1.13' '0.781' '1.697' 
'12/31/11' '7:00' '9711' 'Millbrook' '13.02' '1.758' '1.133' '0.786' '1.699' 
'12/31/11' '6:00' '9710' 'Millbrook' '13.02' '1.76' '1.138' '0.793' '1.707' 
'12/31/11' '5:00' '9709' 'Millbrook' '13.02' '1.763' '1.143' '0.801' '1.719' 
'12/31/11' '4:00' '9708' 'Millbrook' '13.03' '1.765' '1.145' '0.801' '1.729' 
'12/31/11' '3:00' '9707' 'Millbrook' '13.03' '1.763' '1.143' '0.801' '1.741' 
'12/31/11' '2:00' '9706' 'Millbrook' '13.03' '1.763' '1.143' '0.801' '1.748' 
'12/31/11' '1:00' '9705' 'Millbrook' '13.04' '1.763' '1.143' '0.801' '1.753' 
'12/31/11' '0:00' '9704' 'Millbrook' '13.04' '1.763' '1.14' '0.798' '1.763' };

uniqueDays = unique(myData(:,1));

for ind = 1:length(uniqueDays)

    myDay = uniqueDays{ind};
    logThisDay = strcmpi(myDay, myData(:,1));

    thisDayData = myData(logThisDay,:);

    disp(sprintf('********* DATA FOR %s *********', myDay));
    disp(thisDayData(:, 2:end))

end
```